# Crashes on some devices when trying to turn on flash

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, crash-reports, flashlight

I developed an Android application which can turn on the led flash. This appears to work fine on most phones but since the app is downloadable from Google Play I am getting some crash reports in the flashlight.
I even got a report for a Nexus 5, I have the same phone but I dont have any problems whatsoever. This is my code:

```
private ImageButton mFlashButton;
private Parameters mParams;
private Camera mCamera;
private Thread t;
private ImageView ivRing;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.flashlight_fragment,
            container, false);

    ivRing = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivRing);

    // flash switch button
    mFlashButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.flashlight_button);

    // Switch button click event to toggle flash on/off
    mFlashButton.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);

    return view;
}

View.OnClickListener mClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mLightOn) {
            turnOffFlash();
        } else {
            turnOnFlash();
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    SurfaceView preview = (SurfaceView) getView().findViewById(R.id.PREVIEW);
    SurfaceHolder mHolder = preview.getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    turnOffFlash(true);
}

// Turning On flash
private void turnOnFlash() {

    if (!mLightOn) {
        //if camera not found, break
        if (mCamera == null || mParams == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            mParams = mCamera.getParameters();
            mParams.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            mCamera.setParameters(mParams);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mLightOn = true;
        }
    }

    getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}


// Turning Off flash
private void turnOffFlash() {

    if (mLightOn) {
        //if camera is null, break;
        if (mCamera == null || mParams == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            //strobo not running, just turn flash off
            mParams = mCamera.getParameters();
            mParams.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            mCamera.setParameters(mParams);
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mLightOn = false;
        }
        getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
}


@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (mCamera == null) {
        //next line forced closed once, should look into this
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            mParams = mCamera.getParameters();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong, please restart flashlight", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong, please restart flashlight", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

}
```

These are the crash reports I am getting:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1650)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And also this crash report:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void     android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(android.view.SurfaceHolder)' on a null object reference
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:572)
at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:175)
at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1867)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
```

Does anyone have the slightest clue whats going on here? The fact that it does not crash on my Nexus 5 and does on another confuses me..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

May be some devices have not support for flash (may be they do not have flash) so for this purpose you should first check if device is supporting flashlight or not.

```
boolean hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
        .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

if (!hasFlash) {
    // device doesn't support flash
    // Show alert message and close the application
    AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .create();
    alert.setTitle("Error");
    alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!");
    alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // closing the application or what ever you want if device does not support
            finish();
        }
    });
    alert.show();
    return;
}
else {
  //turn on flash light code here....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I already check for that. This code is only for devices with a LED flash.

Answer (score 1):

```
    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
```

is what fails. Youre calling a NPE to another method and not handling the NPE in the method.

Comment: surfaceCreated as a function is really weird, if the camera == null, you try those arguments. One of them is to pass along holder, which also is 0. Since I have no idea what setPreviewDisplay actually is, I would suggest you looking over that part.

Comment: I believe surfaceCreated is called when the activity starts, so if the camera is null at that point I have to instantiate it with Camera.open().
The holder should be instantiated in onStart() except I dont really know why this sometimes fails. In my experience it works everytime.
Thanks for your input by the way!